# What is this phrase?

Tags: grammar

**What does "I seldom go to church" mean?**

What can it be replaced with?

Comment: What can it be replaced with? _Rarely, if ever_, as in, "I rarely, if ever, go to church."

Answer (score 6):

"Seldom" is a somewhat old-fashioned way to say rarely. Hopefully you know what "never" means by now.

So, in answer to how many Sundays a year do you go to church, a person might say:

-I never go to church.

-I seldom go to church.

-I sometimes go to church.

-I frequently go to church.

-I always go to church.

I suspect that you got this data from a survey, and the question was something like "which of these statements best describes your church attendance?" The answers looked something like the list above.

This particular survey has combined the first two categories into "I never or seldom go to church." (It might also combine the last two categories into "I frequently or always go to church.")